# how to include libprotobuf.a in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, android-ndk, protocol-buffers, cocos2d-x, android-ndk-r7

I need to use google's protobuf in my cocos2d-x android project. I include headers and C++ files in project. But when I try to compile project via NDK, compiler return me errors:

`jni/../../Classes/PromowallLibrary/protocol.pb.cpp:55: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::generated_pool()'
jni/../../Classes/PromowallLibrary/protocol.pb.cpp:55: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::FindFileByName(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) const'
jni/../../Classes/PromowallLibrary/protocol.pb.cpp:56: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::LogMessage(google::protobuf::LogLevel, char const*, int)'`

and so on. How can I point to -lprotobuf library? I tried:

`LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lprotobuf \`
 but that is doesn't work

**UPDATE:**
now I try to do in such way - I create static module:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libprotobuf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprotobuf.a
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp \
            .cc

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloworld/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/PromowallLibrary/protocol.pb.cc

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
         $(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libprotobuf
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) $(call import-module,cocos2dx)
```

Now I get such kind of errors:


    `/home/ivan/android/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/libprotobuf.a(common.o): incompatible target
    /home/ivan/android/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/libprotobuf.a(generated_message_util.o): incompatible target
    /home/ivan/android/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/libprotobuf.a(message_lite.o): incompatible target
    /home/ivan/android/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/libprotobuf.a(repeated_field.o): incompatible target
    /home/ivan/android/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ./obj/local/armeabi/libprotobuf.a(wire_format_lite.o): incompatible target`

Comment: check the Android.mk to see how cocos2d-x use libpng or curl, you can use it the same way.

Comment: As I understand I need to create STATIC_MODULE for using any static library .a? Am I right?

Comment: not quite sure, because I didn't use those libs before. but the idea should be correct.